# Is it possible to create a full SEO website with Firebase?

Tags: seo, php, authentication, firebase

I work a lot with PHP, and as many of you know, you have a lot of flexibility when it comes to creating dynamic pages.

You have sessions for authentication, database queries, etc. But the most important thing is that you can configure your site to have friendly URLs and dynamic headers with SEO tags.

Can I create a fully functional website (optimized for SEO) with Firebase just like I would with PHP?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/ for those of us who have never heard of it.   It says it is for making apps, so it looks like to me like it is for phones, not for web.

Answer (score 2):

You can absolutely create web pages with firebase.

Check out [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting), it lets you serve up static websites HTML, CSS, and JS, which are inherently SEO-friendly. You can couple this JAMstack approach with Firebase's storage, database and authentication tools to make a first-class app.

I'm not sure how practical it is compared to a standard dynamic site, but the option is there.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you **CAN'T** create a webpage with firebase.

However, you'll need a JavaScript (web or Node.js or similar) and you can do that. To add Firebase to your app, you'll need a Firebase project, the Firebase SDK, and a short snippet of initialization code that has a few details about your project.

It'll be ok with SEO.